# What is " 1-800-NO-SOFTWARE" in salesforce website

Tags: phone

1-800-NO-SOFTWARE  in salesforce website shows the No software strategy but is it a number or something like that? :)

Comment: It's a phone number; their bit is that you get a service and don't need software.

Comment: which is that number ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On US phones at least the number keys have 3 (or 4) letters on each number, so dialing "1-800-NO-SOFTWARE" actually means dialing 1-800-66-76389273.

Note that that number is too long, but dialing the extra 273 at the end has no effect on most systems and will connect you to 1-800-667-6389, their real number.

It's just a catchy shorthand that's easier to remember than the number.